# How to pass multiple arguments in fast tag in play framework

Tags: playframework

I'm passing a single argument which works fine:

```
#{mytags.customerList 'function':'customersList()' /}
```

How to pass multiple arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
#{mytags.customerList function:'customersList()', arg2:'arg2value' /}
```

Note that if your tags are in the view\tags tags directory you probably don't need to specify #{**mytags**.customerList but just #{customerList

Comment: ' will not come for arguments, ' should not come in 'function'

Comment: Do you mean pass a list to the tag?

Comment: if so #{mytag items:customersList()/} then refer to it as _items in your mytag.html.

Comment: I meant the single quote char('). single quote char should not come for arguments. but 'function' has single quote char

Comment: I am not sure I truly understand your problem. However the correct syntax should be #{mytag arg:'thisisastring', arg1:iamanobject/} no quotes around the arguments name.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use quotes for the names nor parameters
2. Ensure that the tag can accept the parameters (they won't be ignored)

The syntax would be:

```
#{mytags.customerList  param1:value1, param2: value2, param3: value3 /}
```

where `paramN` is the name of the parameter inside the tag and `valueN` corresponds to a value available in the current template